# Timer failure in UNUserNotificationCenter.getNotificationSettings

Tags: swift, timer, permissions, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to start some timers on a view controller, based on whether or not the application has provided push permissions, but the timers are not triggering. Can anyone explain to me why that is?

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

    private var startTime: Date!

    private var countDown: Timer?
    private var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        startTime = Date()

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
            if settings.authorizationStatus == .denied || settings.authorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
                self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.manualFunction(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            } else {
                // Wait two seconds, then start the manual check.
                self.countDown = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { (timer) in
                    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.manualFunction(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                })
            }
        }
    }

    @objc private func manualFunction(_ timer: Timer) {
        // Some function I want to execute whenever the second timer triggers.
    }

}
```

The `viewDidAppear` function used to contain the following code that did work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    startTime = Date()

    self.countDown = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false, block: { [weak self] (timer) in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.manualFunction(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    })
}
```

I've tried making the timers `weak`, I've tried adding `[unowned self]` and `[weak self]` in several spots, without a success. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the `getNotificationSettings` method you're entering the background queue and you should come back to your main queue to handle task that are to be performed in the main queue.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { settings in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Add your tasks here
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't we have to call weak self here